# Why doesn't scala's parallel sequences have a contains method?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-2.9

Why does

```
 List.range(0,100).contains(2)
```

Work, while

```
 List.range(0,100).par.contains(2)
```

Does not?

This is planned for the future?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The non-[teleological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) answer is that it's because `contains` is defined in `SeqLike` but not in `ParSeqLike`.

If that doesn't satisfy your curiosity, you can find that `SeqLike`'s `contains` is defined thus:

```
def contains(elem: Any): Boolean = exists (_ == elem)
```

So for your example you can write

```
List.range(0,100).par.exists(_ == 2)
```

`ParSeqLike` is missing a few other methods as well, some of which would be hard to implement efficiently (e.g. `indexOfSlice`) and some for less obvious reasons (e.g. `combinations` - maybe because that's only useful on small datasets). But if you have a parallel collection you can also use `.seq` to get back to the linear version and get your methods back:

```
List.range(0,100).par.seq.contains(2)
```

As for why the library designers left it out... I'm totally guessing, but maybe they wanted to reduce the number of methods for simplicity's sake, and it's nearly as easy to use `exists`.

This also raises the question, why is `contains` defined on `SeqLike` rather than on the granddaddy of all collections, `GenTraversableOnce`, where you find `exists`? A possible reason is that `contains` for `Map` is semantically a different method to that on `Set` and `Seq`. A `Map[A,B]` is a `Traversable[(A,B)]`, so if `contains` were defined for `Traversable`, `contains` would need to take a tuple `(A,B)` argument; however `Map`'s `contains` takes just an `A` argument. Given this, I think `contains` should be defined in `GenSeqLike` - maybe this is an oversight that will be corrected.

(I thought at first maybe parallel sequences don't have `contains` because searching where you intend to stop after finding your target on parallel collections is a lot less efficient than the linear version (the various threads do a lot of unnecessary work after the value is found: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470162/understanding-parallel-exists-and-find)), but that can't be right because `exists` is there.)

Comment: `indexOfSlice` would make sense since parallel sequences do have order, it's just that they don't execute parallel operations in order. But an efficient, scalable `indexOfSlice` hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks very helpful! I would guess that they simply haven't implemented it yet because it doesn't work as you would expect it to, i.e. return as soon as it finds one value.