# Calling map on a parallel collection via a reference to an ancestor type

Tags: scala, parallel-collections

I tried to make it optional to run a `map` operation sequentially or in parallel, for example using the following code:

```
val runParallel = true
val theList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
(if(runParallel) theList.par else theList) map println //Doesn't run in parallel
```

What I noticed is that the 'map' operation does not run in parallel as I'd expected. Although without the conditional, it would:

```
theList.par map println   //Runs in parallel as visible in the output
```

The type of the expression `(if(runParallel) theList else theList.par)` which I expect to be the closest common ancestor of both types of `theList` and `theList.par` is a scary type that I won't paste here but it's interesting to look at (via scala console:)

```
:type (if(true) theList else theList.par)
```

Why doesn't the `map` on the parallel collection work in parallel?

UPDATE: This is discussed in [SI-4843](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4843) but from the JIRA ticket it's not clear why this was happening on Scala 2.9.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation of why it happens is a long story: in Scala 2.9.x (I don't know about the other versions) those collections methods such as filter or map relies on the `CanBuildFrom` mechanism. The idea is that you have an implicit parameter which is used to create a builder for the new collection:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    b.sizeHint(this) 
    for (x <- this) b += f(x)
    b.result
  }
```

Thanks to this mechanism, the map method is defined only in the `TraversableLike` trait and its subclasses do not need to override it. As you see, inside the method map signature there are many type parameters. Let's look at the trivial ones:

- The `B` which is the type of the elements of the new collection
- The `A` is the type of the elements in the source collection

Let's look at the more complicated ones:

- `That` is the new type of collection, which can be different from the current type. A classical example is when you map for example a BitSet using a toString:

  ```
   scala> val a = BitSet(1,3,5)
   a scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 3, 5)
   scala>  a.map {_.toString}
   res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(1, 3, 5)
  ```

Since it is illegal to create a `BitSet[String]` your map result will be a `Set[String]`
Finally `Repr` is the type of the current collection. When you try to map a collection over a function, the compiler will resolve a suitable CanBuildFrom using the type parameters.

As it is reasonable, the map method has been overridden in parallel collections in `ParIterableLike` as the following:

```
 def map[S, That](f: T => S)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, S, That]): That = bf ifParallel { pbf =>
    executeAndWaitResult(new Map[S, That](f, pbf, splitter) mapResult { _.result })
  } otherwise seq.map(f)(bf2seq(bf))
```

As you can see the method has the same signature, but it uses a different approach: it test whether the provided  `CanBuildFrom` is parallel and otherwise falls back on the default implementation.
Therefore, Scala parallel collections use special CanBuildFrom (parallel ones) which create parallel builders for the map methods.

However, what happens when you do

```
(if(runParallel) theList.par else theList) map println //Doesn't run in parallel
```

is the map method gets executed on the result of

```
  (if(runParallel) theList.par else theList)
```

whose return type is the first common ancestors of both classes (in this case just a certain number of traits mixed togethers). Since it is a common ancestor, is type parameter `Repr` will be some kind of common ancestors of both collections representation, let's call it `Repr1`.

---

**Conclusion**

When you call the `map` method, the compiler should find a suitable `CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]` for the operation. Since our `Repr1` is not the one of a parallel collection, there won't be any `CanBuildFrom[Repr1,B,That]` capable of providing a parallel builder. This is actually a correct behaviour with respect to the implementation of Scala collections, if the behaviour would be different that would mean that every map of non parallel collections would be run in parallel as well.

The point here is that, for how Scala collections are designed in 2.9.x there is no alternative. If the compiler does not provide a `CanBuildFrom` for a parallel collection, the map won't be parallel.